# try to do a public method

Tags: java, android, string, listview, methods

i want to create a method to open a popup when i click on it and the title and the text would be automatic, something like this :

```
    public void Display(String test){



        new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle(getTitle()).setMessage(test).setNeutralButton("close", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        }).show();

        }
```

but test is a String and set Message doesn't accept Strings, and it would come from a resource XML, like Strings.xml. So i don't know ho to do this.
And the 'getTitle()' i don't think it could work. My method to take the title is this one.

```
TextView str = new TextView(this);
        str.setText(parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());
        String title = str.getText().toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

setMessage does accept strings. Look at the documentation:

`setMessage(CharSequence message)`

You can pass a String in. Did you try to compile your code?

Comment: excuse me that's not what i meant, i wanted to put and id in it, but the id refers to a strings...

Comment: Can you explain what you're talking about? You want to put an ID in it? What is "it"? What ID? What "id" refers to a strings?!

Comment: It was something like R.strings.texttodisplay but i found out =)

Answer (score 0):

public void Display(int ID, int position, AdapterView parent){

```
        TextView str1 = new TextView(this);
        str1.setText(parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());
        String title = str1.getText().toString();

        TextView str = new TextView(this);
        str.setText(ID);
        String text = str.getText().toString();

        new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle(title).setMessage(text).setNeutralButton("close", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        }).show();

        }
```

that's it -_-', i made some progress.